# nginx Permissions for WordPress Updates and Files?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

When a WordPress installation folder is set to “www-data:www-data” then I am able to update/install WordPress updates and plugins but can edit the files using SFTP.

When a WordPress installation folder is set to “example:example” I can edit the wordpress files using SFTP but can’t perform WordPress core/plugin install/updates.

Currently have to switch between the two all the time. What permissions can one use to be able to do both? Assuming something along the lines of www-data:example or example:www-data or ideally example:example and add www-data to example group. All of which I’ve tried unsuccessfully, so assuming I’m missing a step. Can someone provide some sample commands to reach this commonly desired end goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [proper permissions setup for NGINX+PHP-FPM](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be).

The important thing to do is having your webserver user added to website's user group:

```
usermod -a -G example www-data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did that but still I am not able to login with the newly created user. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7. I did all the changes as per your tutorial and added this user to www-data. I am not sure how to login to the server with a newly created user. 
I logged with ubuntu user using pem key file and then changed it sudo su root user. I have done all the settings and everything setup according to the link you sent but still i am not able to login with newly created user

Comment: I have also tried this but none of this working for me : https://guides.wp-bullet.com/adding-sftp-user-correct-permissions-nginx-php-fpm/

Comment: "I am not able to login with the newly created user" - where? SFTP or SSH? You should have set the password with `passwd example` and then you are able to log in with that in SSH/SFTP.

Comment: Yes i have setup password with passwd example but i am not able to login in both SSH/SFTP http://prntscr.com/ul0cro

Comment: Your server is configured to support only public key authentication. You must authorize your SSH key (and create it, if you don't have one already) on the server instead of password-based authentication. This is basic SSH stuff, and there are many guides out there.

Comment: Yes, it worked with a password just setting this <PasswordAuthentication yes> in ssh config file. Thank you for help and I really appreciate